# How do I pass empty arguments in Parameterized style scenarios in FitNesse

Tags: fitnesse

I want to pass empty Strings with a Parameterized style scenario like this:

```
| scenario | Test with A "_", B "_" and C "_" | a, b, c |
| ensure | do | type | on | id=field1 | with | @a |
| ensure | do | type | on | id=field2 | with | @b |
| ensure | do | type | on | id=field3 | with | @c |
```

and accordingly I use this code:

```
| Test with A " ", B " " and C " "|
```

It doesn't matter, whether I use " " or "${blank}" for an empty string, instead of empty strings FitNesse parses the arguments into "@a", "@b" and "@c".

Only if I deliver one not empty string, the others pass as empty.

e.g.:

```
| Test with A "dummy", B " " and C "${blank}" |
```

writes "dummy" into field1 and empty strings into the fields 2 and 3.

How can I achieve that all arguments pass as empty?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try passing  the value as [literal text](http://fitnesse.org/FitNesse.UserGuide.FitNesseWiki.MarkupLanguageReference.MarkupLiteralText)

```
|!- Test with A " ", B " " and C " "-!|
```

Although. to me, it sounds like you should use a decision table and not Scenario Table. But that's just me :)